# Получение полного пути каталога

Tags: java, swing

Есть ли какой-то способ выбрать катaлог и получить его адреc?
Как в случае с `JFileChooser` можно получить путь до выбранного файла?

Comment: Посмотрите пож. ссылку http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/SelectadirectorywithaJFileChooser.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Немного модифицировал пример из javadoc для [JFileChooser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html)

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("JPG & GIF Images", "jpg", "gif");
chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File selectedFile = chooser.isMultiSelectionEnabled() ? chooser.getSelectedFiles()[0] : chooser.getSelectedFile();
    System.out.println("a directory: " + selectedFile.getAbsoluteFile().getParent());
    System.out.println("an absolute path: " + selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
}
```